# Dynamic trigger function to be called from multiple tables POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am new to PostgreSQL and wondering if there is a way to create one trigger function for insert and update operations which can be called from multiple tables?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, see e.g. here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Comment: Thanks for the Link. In my case i have 20 main tables & 20 staging tables.
Any event like insert or update on the main tables the data should be inserted/updated on their respective staging tables. Can I accomplish this by creating only one trigger function and call it from different tables?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create one trigger procedure and call it from different tables. From within the trigger procedure you can access several special variables which provide metadata about the table which called the trigger i.e.`TG_TABLE_NAME` and `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA`. Using those metadata you can accurately define what the trigger have to do depending on which table called it.

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> `TG_TABLE_NAME`   Data type name; the name of the table that caused the
>   trigger invocation.
>
> `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` Data type name; the name of the
>   schema of the table that caused the trigger invocation.

The variable `TG_OP` provide the operation which caused the trigger to be called:

> `TG_OP` Data type text; a string of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or TRUNCATE
>   telling for which operation the trigger was fired.

Other very useful special variables are `NEW` and `OLD`. They contain the old and the new data which are changed by the database operation:

> `NEW` Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for
>   INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is
>   unassigned in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.
>
> `OLD` Data type RECORD; variable holding the old database row for
>   UPDATE/DELETE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is
>   unassigned in statement-level triggers and for INSERT operations.